# WP8 Prevent OS from handling LaunchApp NFC tag read

Tags: windows-phone, nfc, windows-phone-8

I've created a Windows Phone 8 application that reads and handles a LaunchApp NFC tag when it is presented to the phone.

By default, when a LaunchApp NFC tag is presented to the phone, the WP8 OS automatically handles the tag read and displays a dialog asking whether the user wants to launch the application or ignore it.

The problem is: In-addition to my application receiving and handling the tag read when a LaunchApp NFC tag is presented, the WP8 OS also displays a dialog prompting the user to launch the application.

Is there any way that I can prevent this dialog from showing and strictly let my application handle the LaunchApp NFC tag?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design the OS will always intercept the LaunchApp Windows NFC type; especially as its the OS's responsibility to launch the application. It has little use to subscribe to the type within your app. I would suggest looking at alternate NDEF types to use which aren't handled by the OS (so avoid MIME types such as URL, and images).

Comment: The Nokia NFC Writer App manages to work around this somehow so it must be possible to take focus of the NFC intents when an app is in the foreground.

Comment: No, it uses a LaunchApp record if you write tags to launch apps. For other information like websites it uses type WELL-KNOWN. Apps may subscribe for these, as the browser does for URIs.